# "No module named xxx" still occurs after package is installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am using python 3.5 in Ubuntu 16.04, but I cannot import some packages even they are installed.

For example, if I `import tqdm`, I will have this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

Then I use `sudo pip3 install tqdm` to install it, I have:

```
seke@seke-deep:~/mengzhao/speakerRNN$ sudo pip3 install tqdm
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /home/seke/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

However, even after this, I still have the `ImportError` message above.

Comment: Do you use virtualenv ? Are you sure that you use the good python ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, I just reinstall the package via:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall xxx
sudo pip3 install xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it was resolved using

```
conda install -c conda-forge tqdm
```

The problem seems to be from conflict between Anaconda and pip and python.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to type:

```
which python
```

at a prompt and check that the python you are calling is the one where tqdm is installed(which is in ~/.local by the look of it)